# Google drive duplicate files

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-sheets

I have this code to delete duplicate files but it is not working as desired, It is on a spreadsheet and you go to tools and click on script manager and gives you three buttons

**StartProcess**

**mark Duplicates**

**deleteDuplicates**

The first one retrieves the files, the second one turns duplicate files in light red, and the third one will supposedly erase them and turn them Red, though what it's doing is to turn them just yellow and I'm not able where to find the mistake please somebody help me

```
function startProcess(){
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().deleteAllProperties();
  try{
    ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers()[0]);
  }catch(e){}
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sh.getDataRange().clear();
  sh.getRange(1,1,1,4).setValues([['fileName (logged @'+Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),'MMM-dd-yyyy HH:mm')+')','fileSize','parent folders tree','fileID']]);
  var trig = ScriptApp.newTrigger('getDriveFilesList_').timeBased().everyMinutes(5).create();
  Logger.log(trig.getUniqueId()+'  '+trig.getHandlerFunction());
  getDriveFilesList_();
}

function getDriveFilesList_(){
  var content = [];
  var startTime = new Date().getTime();
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if( ! PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('numberOfFiles')){
    PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('numberOfFiles',0);
  }

  var numberOfFiles = Number(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('numberOfFiles'));
  Logger.log(numberOfFiles);
  var max = numberOfFiles+10000;
  if( ! PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('continuationToken')){
    var files = DriveApp.getFiles();
   // var files = DriveApp.getFolderById('0B3qSFd_____MTFZMDQ').getFiles();// use this line and comment the above if you want to process a single folder
   // use your chozen folder ID of course (available from the browser url , the part after "https://drive.google.com/?authuser=0#folders/")
  }else{
    var files = DriveApp.continueFileIterator(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('continuationToken'))
    }
  while(files.hasNext() && numberOfFiles<(max)){
    var file = files.next()
    if(file.getSize()>0){
      numberOfFiles++;
      var folder = '(shared)';
      if(file.getParents().hasNext()){folder = getTree_(file)}
      content.push([file.getName(),file.getSize(),folder,file.getId()])
    }    
    if(new Date().getTime()-startTime > 250000){break};
  }
  sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow()+1,1,content.length,content[0].length).setValues(content);
  if(!files.hasNext()){ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers()[0]);Logger.log('done !'); sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow()+1,1).setValue('All files processed ('+numberOfFiles+' found)')};
  var continuationToken = files.getContinuationToken()
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('numberOfFiles',numberOfFiles);
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('continuationToken',continuationToken);
}

function markDuplicates(){
  handleDuplicates_(false)
}

function trashDuplicates(){
  handleDuplicates_(true)
}

function handleDuplicates_(trash){  
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sh.setFrozenRows(1);
  sh.sort(1);
  var data = sh.getDataRange().getValues()
  var headers = data.shift()
  var lastComment = data.pop();
  var toDelete = [];
  var item = data[0];
  for(var n=1 ; n<data.length; n++){
    if(data[n][0]==item[0] && data[n][1]==item[1]){
      toDelete.push('delete '+ n);
    }
    item=data[n];
  }
  var marker =   sh.getRange(2,1,data.length,1).getBackgrounds();
  for(var n in data){
    if(!trash){marker.push(['#FFF'])};
    if(toDelete.indexOf('delete '+n)>-1 && !trash){
      marker[n][0] = '#F99';
    }
    if(toDelete.indexOf('delete '+n)>-1 && trash){
      if(marker[n][0]==='#ff9999'){
        try{
        DriveApp.getFileById(data[n][3]).setTrashed(trash);
        marker[n][0] = '#F33';
        }catch(err){Logger.log(err)}
      }else{
        marker[n][0] = '#FF9';  3
      }
    }
  }
  sh.getRange(2,1,marker.length,1).setBackgrounds(marker);
}

function getTree_(file){
  var tree = [];
  var folderP = file.getParents()
  while (folderP.hasNext()){
    var folder = folderP.next();
    folderP = folder.getParents();
    tree.push(folder.getName());
  }
  return tree.reverse().join('/');
}
```

Comment: Share the spreadsheet that you r working. Thanks

Comment: Here is the link make a copy so it can work on your drive

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Aj0cW5YX5rvcdHBHZXRmUGc5WWtMZTUzWndjTHhUX0E&usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

I found a few issues in your code so I've created a new ajrHandleDuplicates_() which seems to do what you are after. I've only run simple tests from a single folder and I've disabled the continuation trigger.

You can run the script from [this sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iaZCdj9qxrD6xSL_sanjO3O2JoS5T_SxNPOFGTKMqxQ/edit?usp=sharing) (and take a copy, although you've got edit access) and you can drop files into [this folder](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BxRtIprIrwuzfkIwUEJDYVRLQkN5UnRRLTRmcmhzSHhvNF9DMERadXVIRG5RZ3FmN1lQQW8&usp=sharing) to test it (you'll see the results of my last test). I made a little text file on my desktop and dropped that in and renamed it.

Comment: Sure I can see it actually works now but there's just one thing, before I could just share it and it would check for the files into my drive now should I leave blank the parenthesis of getFolderById so It shows it that way?

Comment: If you uncomment line 84 (var files = DriveApp.getFiles();) and comment out line 85 it'll search your whole GDrive. But this'll probably go over the 6min execution limit so you'd need to uncomment all of the various trigger code as well, and you'd want to take a copy into your own GDrive first as this sheet is public.

Comment: I've re-enabled all of the trigger code in my copy of the script.

Comment: Hello, I have made a copy of your sheet and I have added my folder id in line 85. This works for only that folder ID. Is it possible to adapt it so it would also search into all related subfolders of that main folder ID ? Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: You could certainly use Folder.getFolders() to get all of its children and then recursively repeat the process.

Answer (score -1):

I tried to use the script in the given answer and found that it did not work at all. The code is very poorly organized and it appears to missing relevant portions. Even if the code was working I would not expect it to run well as the [Google App Script limits](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) would be hit very quickly. Here are a few limits that the script would hit:

1. **30 Second Limit** - Custom functions can only run for 30 seconds which is not nearly enough time to scan all the files in most Google Drive accounts.
2. **6 minute limit** - If we didn't hit the custom function limit we would hit the 6 minute script execution limit.
3. **Memory Limit** - this limit isn't documented but storing each file that is scanned to compare against others is going to hit a memory limit rather quickly.

Also, I wouldn't trust the script as it does not appear to be comparing an MD5 on each file.

My recommendation is to not try to solve this problem inside a Google Sheet. Instead, build the code outside of a sheet using [Google Drive's API](https://developers.google.com/drive). Or an even simpler approach is to use [Clean Drive for Google Drive](https://cleandrive.app) which will find the duplicate file for you. It can handle large accounts with millions of files and does not hit any of the limit issues stated above.

FYI, I'm the creator of [Clean Drive](https://cleandrive.app) so I am a little biased but I think you will be too if you use it.